# Does Crontab queue a job?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, job-control

I have scheduled a crontab job for every 2 minutes. But I have recently started to notice that the program takes more time (approx 7-8 mins)to finish execution.
So does cron queues all the jobs that are not getting executed or it just skips the job execution if it finds the previous trigger is not yet finished ?

If so (i.e it queues up these jobs), is there any way to check this queue?
My server runs on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

`cron` execute jobs on the schedule you define. If you do not have any logic in to the script which prevent simultaneous execution they will run in parallel.

If you have such logic in to the script it do what is defined.